# parse xml file and output to text file

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Trying to parse an xml file (config.xml) with ElementTree and output to a text file.  I looked at other similar ques here but none helped me. Using Python 2.7.9

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('config.xml')
notags = ET.tostring(tree,encoding='us-ascii',method='text')
print(notags)
```

OUTPUT

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./python_element", line 9, in <module>
notags = ET.tostring(tree,encoding='us-ascii',method='text')
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1126, in      tostring
ElementTree(element).write(file, encoding, method=method
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 814, in write
_serialize_text(write, self._root, encoding)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1005, in   _serialize_text
for part in elem.itertext():
AttributeError: 

> 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'itertext'
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `tree` (`ElementTree` object), pass an `Element` object. You can get an root element using `.getroot()` method:

```
notags = ET.tostring(tree.getroot(), encoding='utf-8',method='text')
```

Comment: I tried adding the notags line from above but when I rerun the script I get blank lines.  The xml looks like: `<?xml version="1.0"?>

<R3Configuration>
   <R3Instance
              instanceName="SAP1"
                 gatewayService="9999"
                 gatewayHost="internet.com"
      />
  </R3Instance>
</R3Configuration>` and the program now looks like: `#!/usr/bin/python
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('config3.xml')
notags = ET.tostring(tree.getroot(),encoding='utf-8',method='text')
print(notags)`

Comment: @Seattle427, Could you post the content of `config.xml` somewhere so that I can try with the file?